# What happens if I call .attr(attributeName, null)? Is the attribute removed?

Tags: jquery

I want to conditionally add an attribute using jQuery:

```
var $this = this
.append(...)
...

if (someCondition)
    this.attr(...)

return $this;
```

That single silly conditional attribute addition breaks the beauty of my chain of jQuery method invocations. However, this could be overcome if `.attr(someAttr, null)` deleted the attibute `someAttr`:

```
return this
.append(...)
....
.attr(someAttr, someCondition ? someValue : null);
```

So the question is: Does `.attr(someAttr, null)` delete the attribute `someAttr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an attribute using jquery, use [.removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444892/jquery-1-3-issue-with-setting-an-attribute-value/444970#444970), as of 1.3 at least using null would actually cause the overloaded function to call just `.attr(attributeName)`, returning the current value.

To set an empty value, use `.attr(attributeName, '')`

For conditional adding of an attribute, use

```
var val = $("#selector").attr(attributeName); // the current value, undefined if not set
$("#selector").attr(attributeName, val ? val : valToSet);  
// if the value is set, use it, otherwise pass the default in
```

Comment: Take another look at the question. The `if()` is what OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't *delete* the attribute, but it should work to clear its value. Though to be sure you may want to set it to an empty string instead.

```
.attr(someAttr, someCondition ? someValue : '');
```

Or you could pass it a function that runs the condition:

```
.attr(someAttr, function(i,attr){  return someCondition ? someValue : ''; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but if you are trying to remove an attribute, why not just use `removeAttr`?

http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: I don't need to remove the attribute. It doesn't exist. What I want is to conditionally add an attribute without breaking the chain of jQuery method invocations.